# Asp.net textbox not chaning ID while runat="Server" is set

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, runatserver

I have a below control in my master page of asp.net website.

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg12" runat="server" Text="" Style="display: none"></asp:TextBox>
```

On Test site in browser's view page it shows below Tag(changed ID and Name becuase of runat server).

```html
<input name="ctl00$txtMsg12" type="text" value="a" id="ctl00_txtMsg"...
```

But in production it shows below rendered html code.(Only Name is changed not ID)

```html
<input name="ctl00$txtMsg12" type="text" value="a" id="txtMsg12"
```

I have checked all the ASPx and CS file all are same. What can be a reason behind it?

I am using Framework 4.0

Comment: Is there a reason behind why you want a consistent naming for Id?

Comment: Yes, it is been used in javascript multiple places. I can use Clientmode=static and move but not sure what is the reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

When any control be in `ContentPlaceHold` will add `ContentPlaceHold` name in the start of any control inside it . so ctl00 is `ContentPlaceHoldID` and control will be ctl00 _txtMsg Check This [article](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs)

Comment: Correct..But my question is why it is different in Test site than the Production.. If you check my post again and see rendered input tag then you will find that name is getting changed in Production but ID is not.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `clientIDMode` set to `AutoId` in your local web.config.
If it's not set in production web.config I think it might use `clientIdMode="Static"` which would explain different behaviours.

More on ClientIdMode:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No.. I am not using clientIDMode="Static"  neither in Test nor in Production site.